# How to use CTRL + B in Python Robot Framework while using Telnet Library

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, telnet, robotframework

I am new to Robot framework and automation.Now I have a scenario to execute commands in robot and grep the result.I have some cases where i have to use CTRL+B (or) BREAK command in the telnet and type a command in the next line.I have tried something like this seeing the keyword :

```
Write Control Character    BRK
```

But this is not working.Can anyone please help me out with this

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the keyword throw an error?

Comment: No error is thrown.But it doesnt perform break stament.I mean in case i comment that line and give some irrelevent command it automatically breaks and the remaining codes work.I have kept that method as alternative.But i was thinking executing break using robot command would be more opted method.But i am not  able to acheive it